# Switch Map on same mapdiv using leaflet on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Please don't mark as duplicate this question as it's not the same question at all.

So my issue here is I have device on/off switch on a page. So when someone do off it only show all the marker on leaflet map with off data only. Same will happen with on...so if user clicks on  then it filter all the off data and only show on data on leaflet map....

So leaflet map define like following:

```
<div id="mapid2" style="height:400px; width:90%;">
```

When page refresh and user come on to the page for the first time mapid2 will show all on/off data. But when user clicks on OFF data or ON data then mapid2 will only show ON or OFF marker data on the same mapid2.

Something very simple but I am missing.....Thanks guys in advanced.:)

Comment: This should be very easy to search for examples.

Comment: I did but not found any suitable one so if you know any which resolve my issue or similar case then please drop here thanks

Comment: So you basically have two datasets: one for the off state, and one for the on state. You can add each of these sets to a `L.FeatureGroup` and let the switch remove/add them to the map?